# Facebook iOS SDK v4.0 Check User Session State

Tags: session, facebook-ios-sdk

In the new Facebook iOS SDK, the entire login process has been revamped. The old `[FBSession activeSession].isOpen` trick doesn't work anymore. How can I reliably determine the state of a user's session in the new SDK?

My current thoughts are simply checking if `[FBSDKProfile currentProfile]` is nil, but that doesn't seem like it would be 100% accurate, or the proper, most direct way to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi, Please refer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908560/how-to-track-facebook-password-change-and-profile-changes. [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] is always as token even user changed the password/removed the app in facebook.  can you help me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are some changes on v4.0. You can check all of them here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x

In order to check user's session, now you should use `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]`.

> `FBSession.activeSession` has been replaced with `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` and `FBSDKLoginManager`. There is no concept of session state. Instead, use the manager to login and this sets the `currentAccessToken` reference.

Comment: So, just check if that singleton is `nil`?

Comment: Exactly, there is no session state anymore. If you have an access token, you are able to use Facebook services.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, but no matter how I log the user in the `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()` is always `nil`. Is there another way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: @hannes check this question [ios Facebook SDK v4.x access token null despite being logged in via FBSDKLoginButton](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29434392/1492173)

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but I was having the same issue because I did not set the access token. In the `didCompleteWithResult` login button delegate function, you have to set the access token by calling `FBSDKAccessToken.setAccessToken(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult.token)`.