# Facebook SDK 4.0 - currentAccessToken still nil within loginButton didCompleteWithResult

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am upgrading to Facebook SDK 4.X and I am having trouble determining what to do immediately after login.

In the Facebook Delegate's `loginButton didCompleteWithResult` method, it returns successfully (skips the `error` if statement), so for my system I need to register the user with my server, so in the previous version of the Facebook SDK, I would send the access token to my server.

But in this `didCompleteWithResult` method, `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` is still returning `nil`

all my AppDelegate lifecycle methods return the facebook functions, so I'm not sure what else could be happening incorrectly, or where I should expect the AccessToken to be populated

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot the call the `FBSDKApplicationDelegate` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30406194/561485.

The documentation explains more about the [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKApplicationDelegate/#application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was facing this issue as I was using another Google sign in as well. So, the url wasn't handled by facebook sdk. I had to change the app delegate methods as follows:

```
 @available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool {
       let gHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                 annotation: [:])
        let fHandle = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, options: options)
        return gHandle || fHandle

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```